# python validate payload based on open API3 specification schema

Tags: python, openapi, jsonschema, connexion

I am trying to find a way to validate the payload based on OPEN API3.0.0 specification schema using connexion 2.14.0 and FlaskApp.

Open API specification:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title:  API
  version: 0.0.0
paths:
  "/":
    post:
      operationId: post_func
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json; charset=utf-8:
            schema:
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CalculationRequest"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Calc successfully finished
        '400':
          description: Exception during payload parsing.
    get:
      operationId: get_func
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'Use post and send data' 
components:
  schemas:
    CalculationRequest:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: false
      required:
        - accountGroupId
        - accountIds
      properties:
        accountGroupId:
          type: string
        accountIds:
          type: array
          items:
```

Example flask app using connexion

```
def post_func():
    some action

def get_func():
   some action

options = {'swagger_path': '/swagger-ui/', "swagger_ui": True}
application  = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir='./', options = options)
application.add_api('api_specification.yaml', strict_validation=True)
app = application.app
```

So, I expect that the payload not corresponding to the API specification will throw a validation error.
Example correct post request:

{"accountGroupId":"accounts-1234",
"accountIds":
[accounts-1",
"accounts-2"
]}

Expected response: 200, pass validation schema
Actual response: 200, pass the validation schema

Example incorrect post request
{"account_group_id":"accounts-1234",
"account_ids":
[accounts-1",
"accounts-2"
]}
Expected response: 400, bad request (does not pass validation schema)
Actual response: 200, pass the validation schema.

So, it seems that payload validation based on OPEN API 3 does not work with connexion.

I have tried adding "strict_validation" flag and setting additionalProperties to false, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/spec-first/connexion/issues/837), but in vain.

Has anyone faced the similar problem?
Many thanks!

Comment: the question is not clear,  please ask like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide the code which results in the unexpected behaviour.